# According to Kant, are bad consequences of permitted actions imputable to the agent?

Tags: kant, responsibility

According to Kant, can permitted actions have culpable consequences?

> bad consequences are not imputable to the agent who acts dutifully

Does that mean bad consequences are not "imputable" only when we perform an *obligatory* duty?

> Kant sees all free actions as being obligatory, meaning prescribed or
> prohibited, or as being permitted (V 27:513.12–18)

Comment: i definitely can't live like this, anyway. haha

Comment: i *think* it's practically incoherent. a maxim for deontological permission, then consequentialism then another maxim for every bad consequence? you would be paralysed.

Comment: In the famous murderer case, Kant says you should be honest with the killer, even though it’ll probably lead to his victim’s death. If I have time later I’ll write a properly cited answer.

Comment: no i mean when you are under no obligation @Hokon can your actions then have bad consequences?

Comment: Ahhh thank you for the clarification, not sure.

Comment: it may not actually be as strict as i suppose @Hokon there are only a few cases when we can foresee evil actions as a consequence of our permitted behaviours. but i'm not sure it's attractive, if only because you need a lot of clarity on what is permitted if you are not going to fall into incoherence

Comment: i found this @Hokon which has dulled my enthusiasm https://philarchive.org/archive/LIUARD#:~:text=The%20Doctrine%20of%20Doing%20and%20Allowing%20(DDA)%20states%20that%20there,merely%20allowing%20harm%20to%20happen.